# How to detect change in typescript object in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string which contains error messages on the form.

```
  error: String;
```

I need to enable or disable submit button based on this string. If it's empty then enable or disable it.
How do I detect any changes to the error string in angular 6?

Comment: Can you please show the code how you are enabling or disabling

Answer (score 0):

I just did below thing on the submit button and in `isError` function I check if it's empty.

```
[disabled]="isError()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go and read about Angular forms and form validation https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

There are different ways you can achieve that but for what you need a required validator would do. Below is just one example of how to do it.

HTML FILE

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="generalForm">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="error"  formControlName="error">
</form>

 <button class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!f.valid" (click)="save()"> Save </button>
```

TS FILE

```
 generalSettingsForm = new FormGroup({
    error: new FormControl("",Validators.required),    
  });
```